# Asterisk or Digit in IPV4 or IPV6 validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My intention is to get the following validated using regex

```
10.10.*.1
10.10.0.1
10.10.255.1
10.10.10.*
10.10.*.*
2001:db8:3333:4444:5555:6666:7777:8888
684D:1111:222:3333:4444:5555:6:*
2001:db8:3333:4444:5555:6666:*:*
684D:1111:222:3333:4444:5555:*:77
```

Is there any possible way to get the `single` regex for the above problem?

I have tried the below regex but it is matching only ipv4 and ipv6. I am unable to match asterisk in the regex.

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$|^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$|^\s*((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2})|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,4})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(:(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}(?:(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}|\*))|:)))(%.+)?\s*$
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Andreas I have updated my question and added the regex which I have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(10|2001)(\.10|:db8)((\.\d+|\.\*)|(:3{4}))((\.1|\.\*)|(:4{4}))(:5{4}:6{4}:(7{4}|\*):(8{4}|\*))?
```

There are maybe better solutions from this, but it should work for your case.

Comment: It is working for IPV6. Is it possible to handle IPV4 as well?

Comment: Also, IPV6 can start from any it is not necessary to start with 2001.

Comment: This regex matches IPV4 too, not just IPV6. OK, then we need other regex for that

Comment: (10|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})(\.10|:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})((\.\d+|\.\*)|(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}))((\.1|\.\*)|(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}))(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|\*):([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|\*))?

Comment: The previous regex matches any IPV6 addresses. Also, It matches IPV4 that you wrote. If you need to match any IPV4 address too please let me know.

Comment: Yes, I have to match both IPV4 and IPV6. and this second regex is not working. I have tried on regex101.com